# How do I login on jaspersoft 6 Community using sample superuser account type

Tags: login

I am just getting into BI and reporting at its scale, I've picked Jaspersoft after initially going for Pentaho. My intention is to embed the reports I create into an existing CakePHP 3.x application.

I have installed Jaspersoft v6 Community edition with sample data on windows 8. Its running smoothly and I can login with jasperadmin jasperadmin credentials. My problem is I cannot login with the superuser account so that I can create organisations and get the same view in the tutorial videos.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: The title of this confused the hell out of me :)

Comment: @burgi. Sorry for the confusion.  I'll edit the title.

Comment: That's ok, the new title is better just not as funny - maybe it's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaspersoft Community Edition does not have an organization admin account. It only has a system admin account.

From [Jaspersoft Community: Administrator Login](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v56/administrator-login)

> **Administrators log in on the standard login page, using the following default passwords:**
>
> Commercial editions:
>   system admin: username `superuser` and password `superuser`
>   organization admin: username `jasperadmin` and password `jasperadmin`
>
> Community project:
>   system admin: username `jasperadmin` and password `jasperadmin`
>
> For security reasons, always change the default administrator passwords immediately after installing JasperReports Server.